# How can I paste NeoVim registers in terminal mode?

Tags: copy-paste, neovim

When using NeoVim's `:terminal` feature, I'd like to be able to paste text from a register.

When working with a standard text buffer, I frequently use two methods to paste text from a register:

- in Normal mode: `"{register}p`
- in Insert mode: `<C-r>{register}`

I can't get these commands to work the way I'd like them to in a terminal buffer. When the terminal buffer is in Normal mode, I can use `"{register}p` to append the contents of a register at the end of the current command line. Sometimes I'd like to insert text at the start of the current command line, or midway through it, and it seems like there's no way of doing that using this command.

It occurs to me that this should be possible by switching to Terminal mode (which seems to be the terminal buffer equivalent to Insert mode) and using the `<C-r>{register}` command. But the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> is sent directly to my shell. I'm using the bash shell, which maps these keys to the [reverse search](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-History.html) feature, so I find myself looking at this prompt:

```
(reverse-i-search)`':
```

Is there any way that I can use the `<C-r>{register}` in Terminal mode?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, also try the [Vi and Vim SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com) :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nvim is conservative about handling *any* keys (except `<C-\><C-N>`) in terminal-mode, so CTRL-R isn't handled by default. Also, Nvim has no idea about which application is running inside `:terminal`, so `p` just blindly sends text to the input stream.

Having said that, you can use `:tnoremap` to get a similar effect for CTRL-R:

```
:tnoremap <expr> <C-R> '<C-\><C-N>"'.nr2char(getchar()).'pi'
```

Comment: In wrapping my head around how that `:tnoremap` command works, I now realise that it is indeed possible to make `"{reg}p` insert text at any arbitrary point in the current command line. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I find the interactive search feature in Bash useful and I'd like to be able to continue to use `ctrl-r` for that. I've adapted your suggested mapping by using `<C-\><C-r>` as the trigger. I'm going to make a habit of using `<C-\>` as a "leader" for Terminal mode mappings (since `<C-\><C-n>` sets a precedent for this).

Comment: Also, I've set up colors for [`TermCursor`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/syntax.html#hl-TermCursor) and `TermCursorNC`, which makes it clear where the pasted text will appear in the command line.

Comment: Good idea about `TermCursorNC`. As a leader key you might consider a META/ALT chord, there are many unused ones available and they work well in Nvim (and `:te`).

Comment: A good accompanying change is to have an alternative command for reverse searching: https://askubuntu.com/questions/581916/terminal-replacing-ctrlr-with-ctrlk

Answer (score 3):

There is actually no need to insert control characters in the configuration.
You can let Nvim unescape them for you.

```
"Enable CTRL-V in terminal mode
tnoremap <expr> <C-R> '<C-\><C-N>"'.nr2char(getchar()).'pi'
```

Answer (score 2):

### In the docs

The neovim documentation (`:help terminal-input`) suggests this:

```
To simulate i_CTRL-R in terminal-mode:
    :tnoremap <expr> <C-R> '<C-\><C-N>"'.nr2char(getchar()).'pi'
```

### For normal keyboard

Unfortunately this clashes with the terminal history search C-r. You can modify this to work with the Alt key on a normal keyboard:

```
To simulate i_CTRL-R in terminal-mode:
    :tnoremap <expr> <A-R> '<C-\><C-N>"'.nr2char(getchar()).'pi'
```

### For Macbook

But that doesn't work on a MacbookPro because Alt is not a thing and NeoVim doesn't do bindings for Command⌘. This works on a MacbookPro and so far I've felt it's pretty comfortable:

```
To simulate i_CTRL-R in terminal-mode:
    :tnoremap <expr> <C-\><C-\> '<C-\><C-N>"'.nr2char(getchar()).'pi'
```

---

DISCLAIMER: I'm using `set -o vi` in the terminal. So there's that. Your mileage may vary. Oh and I'm not using iTerm2. I'm using the Alacritty terminal emulator. Thus when I do a history search all I do is `Ctrl-[` then just `nnnnN` until I find my stuff. Or `Ctrl-[`, `/`, `<searchterm><enter>`, `nnNn` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a lua translation of the solutions from the other answers:

```lua
vim.keymap.set('t', '<c-r>', function()
  local next_char_code = vim.fn.getchar()
  local next_char = vim.fn.nr2char(next_char_code)
  return '<C-\\><C-N>"'..next_char..'pi'
end, { expr = true })
```